# Does find my iPhone still work if I transfer my number to another device?

Tags: iphone

My phone is currently trapped under a collapsed building. It is showing up on find my iPhone so it's still alive! I ordered a new phone as I don't know when or if they can recover it. If I activate the new phone with my old number, will I lose the ability to track my old phone? I'd like to keep watching it to see if it continues to survive.

Comment: The battery will likely die soon, so I wouldn't worry about keeping it active, but you could ask your carrier to give your old phone a new number and continue service, then put your old number on the new phone.

Answer (score 1):

If you transfer the number to a new cellular data plan, and the phone is not connected to a wifi hotspot, your phone won't be able to report current GPS coordinates to Apple's Find My Phone servers. In short, I think the answer is no, but as @HLLB pointed out, your phone's battery will probably die before the phone number port is completed, so better get to digging!

Answer (score 0):

I do not know about iPhone tracking, but about mobile networks.

The phone number (MSISDN) does not belong to or reside on the phone. The number is on a database (HLR) in the mobile network where is is related to the SIM (IMSI). You can remove SIM from phone and transfer it to another phone.

The network operator can change issue a new SIM and transfer the number to this SIM so you have a seamless changeover.

I doubt this would affect Apple's identification of the phone which would be related to its identification number (IMEI).